# Which programming languages can only run on JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Depending on where you live, trying to download the JVM may result in [a message like this](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_embargoed.xml):

> The Java(TM) cannot be downloaded to your machine. You are located in an embargoed country.

In my opinion, teachers in IT should inform children about problems that can emerge from this restricted access (OpenJVM is not Oracle JVM and is not used in enterprise/government). No official JVM updates means no fixing of vulnerabilities, exploits, bugs and so on. If JVM is officially unavailable it is reason enough to inform children about the possible consequences.

Hence my question: what languages can **only** run on JVM/OpenJVM?

Comment: **Note: Stack Overflow is not a place to discuss politics. Please keep comments focused on the actual question. Any comments about the politics involved are off-topic and non-constructive and will be removed. Thanks.**

Answer (score 4):

Java bytecode [can be recompiled to LLVM](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/java/trunk/docs/java-frontend.txt) and [the same probably applies for Scala](http://greedy.github.io/scala-llvm/) - quite possibly for all of them. [Clojure also has an implementation on the CLR](http://clojure.org/clojureclr). All other languages that can run on the JVM already have their own implementations (like Python and Ruby).

Technically, I don't think there are many languages that can *only* run on (Oracle's) JVM. The question, of course, is whether all the alternative implementations are of any help to you, considering that they may be forbidden as well.

Furthermore, I sense that this isn't the point of your question: you said that a given alternative may not be used over there because it isn't an "official" product. If people, corporations or the government actively and consciously choose a specific implementation over any alternatives, then by definition there is no answer for them.

Answer (score 3):

You can't download the JVM officially from the [`www.java.com`](http://www.java.com) website OR other Oracle's websites as it has been embargoed for your nation. But, there are still other means (sources) like [`en.softonic.com`](http://en.softonic.com) and several others which won't bar you for downloading the JVM.

Next, once you have JVM installed in your machine, you can run and execute all the JVM supported languages like Java, Scala, Jython and so on in your machine. It has nothing to do with your location and position once you have JVM in your machine. I wish you successful alternate downloads and enjoy the languages like Java, etc.

Also, please refer to this link for list of more such languages:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages

Comment: It might be worth noting that possibly localization is not supported (for dates, currencies, etc.) and it will probably default to English, unless the country does have a language that is used in a supported country.

Comment: I agree with your point too @skiwi, but I guess russian timestamps and currencies are available and they mightn't have been taken down as the restriction from Russia might be lifted anytime!!!